# Custom error messages in Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The scenario is quite straight-forward:

I have a model with some fields that are required. Let's say one of them is a `TextField` which can't  be `blank`.
I also have a `ModelSerializer` (Django Rest Framework) that represents that model.

When an empty string is used to set that field through the serializer the error returned comes from the model itself (`This field can't be blank`).

I would like to override the error messages only in the serializer level, without the need to explicitly re-specifying every field in the serializer (which I believe is against the DRY principle), having to write a `validate_` method for each field and raise my own `ValidationError` or having to change the error messages in the `Model` level (because sometimes the context of the error message matters to my use-case and the error message should be given accordingly).

In other words, is there a way to override error messages in the serializer level as easy as it is for a `ModelForm`:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        error_messages = {"field1": {"required": _("For some reason this is a custom error message overriding the model's default")}}
```

Comment: DRF is calling django field validators at time of validation. So errors will be coming from here, not from DRF. The idea is to try specify error message on model or field level, because as I can see there are no way to override these messages with DRF.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**EDIT:** I see that this question still receives some views, so it is important to note that there's another approach, much cleaner than the original answer I posted here.

You can just use the [extra_kwargs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) attribute of the serializer's Meta class, like so:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        extra_kwargs = {"username": {"error_messages": {"required": "Give yourself a username"}}}
```

**Original answer:**

Using @mariodev 's answer I created a new class in my project that does that:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, ModelSerializerOptions

class CustomErrorMessagesModelSerializerOptions(ModelSerializerOptions):
    """
    Meta class options for CustomErrorMessagesModelSerializerOptions
    """
    def __init__(self, meta):
        super(CustomErrorMessagesModelSerializerOptions, self).__init__(meta)
        self.error_messages = getattr(meta, 'error_messages', {})

class CustomErrorMessagesModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    _options_class = CustomErrorMessagesModelSerializerOptions

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomErrorMessagesModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Run through all error messages provided in the Meta class and update
        for field_name, err_dict in self.opts.error_messages.iteritems():
            self.fields[field_name].error_messages.update(err_dict)
```

The first one gives the possibility to add a new `Meta` class attribute to the serializer as with the `ModelForm`. 
The second one inherits from `ModelSerializer` and uses @mariodev's technique to update the error messages.

All is left to do, is just inherit it, and do something like that:

```
class UserSerializer(CustomErrorMessagesModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        error_messages = {"username": {"required": "Give yourself a username"}}
```

Comment: class `ModelSerializerOptions` is not available in Django-rest-framework release.

Comment: Note: you might want to set both `required` and `blank` for Char fields.

Comment: From the docs: "Please keep in mind that, if the field has already been explicitly declared on the serializer class, then the `extra_kwargs` option will be ignored."

Answer (score 30):

I tried to create a simple `Serializer` rather than a `ModelSerializer`. Probably because of that the accepted answer with `extra_kwargs` by Gabriel Amram didn't work for me. Another top answer by @mariodev did work but I was looking for a more elegant solution and found one. Turns out that the `Field` class accepts `error_messages` as a parameter, which is a dictionary that overrides the default error messages. Here is the [reference to the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#error_messages). It's the same format as described in the accepted answers. Here is an example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    client_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, error_messages={'required': 'Custom error message'})
```

Comment: In my case I was dealing with an `ChoiceField` where I had to add `error_messages={"invalid_choice": "can be either this or that'"}`

Comment: where can I find a list of my choices for the key of this dictionary? you used `required` here, that checks the `required=True` constraint. is the process the same for other arguments?

Answer (score 26):

In your serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].error_messages['required'] = u'My custom required msg'
```

Please notice that some error messages consist of `%s` placeholders like:

```
'invalid': _("'%s' value must be either True or False."),
```

for `BooleanField`.

So you need to go over `default_error_messages` part in each field type in the DRF's [`fields.py`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/2.4.4/rest_framework/fields.py), to use it properly.

Comment: i have to admit this is not as clean as the `ModelForm` technique, but it does do what I need

Comment: The only thing work for me! The others don't. I'm using `djangorestframework==3.11.0`

Answer (score 16):

`unique` seemed to be ignored from `error_messages`, so I had to take a different approach.

```
email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[
    UniqueValidator(
        queryset=models.Client.objects.all(),
        message="My custom error",
    )]
)
```

It's simpler (yet less flexible, less reusable) than @gabriel-amram's, but far less hacky than @mariodev's.

Comment: This worked for me - 20.03.2020. I wonder why "unique" error messages can't be overriden using `extra_kwargs`?

Comment: This worked for me. But Its not showing up or getting return as part of response to the client so that client can show the actual error message,  but I get this message instead "Request failed with status code 400"

Answer (score 6):

Another approach for UniqueValidator (for using with ModelSerializer):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Find UniqueValidator and set custom message
    for validator in self.fields['email'].validators:
        if isinstance(validator, validators.UniqueValidator):
            validator.message = _('This email already exist on this site')
```

Answer (score 5):

I just spent an hour ripping my hair out over this, so figured I'd post an update here in case anyone else finds it useful.

I'm using djangorestframework version 3.10.3, and for whatever reason, it seems that drf no longer uses the 'required' key in the error_messages dict to allow customization of an error message for a missing value. Instead it uses 'blank'.

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = (
            'description',
        )

        extra_kwargs = {
            'description': {'error_messages': {'blank': "Please provide a description"}},
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

DRF3.0 expects us to explicitly define the validators for fields if we wish to override the default model validators. This can be done by passing extra_kwargs and explicitly defining the validators for whichever field
you seem necessary. Also you can even specify your own custom validator which can be reused again for different fields or even other serializers

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validation-in-rest-framework

```
# my_app/validators.py
def validate_required(value):
    # whatever validation logic you need
    if value == '' or value is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('This field is required.')

# my_app/serializers.py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        extra_kwargs = {"field1": {"validators": [validators.validate_required,]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note since I played with this for awhile, if you're using something like a URLField that just adds a URLValidator, it doesn't seem to use the `error_messages`, so I did something similar to @Hugo's answer:

```
class Meta:
    extra_kwargs = {"url_field": {"validators": [validators.URLValidator(message="My error message")]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate function in serializers.py and call it from serializer class

```py
def checkFields(fields):
    for field in fields:
        fields[field].error_messages['blank']=fields[field].error_messages['required'] = 'Please enter %s'%field
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is the code that inherits the model's error message. 
There is also a module, so download it if you want.
If there's a problem, leave it in the comments.

https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-inherits-error-messages/#files

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.relations import HyperlinkedRelatedField
from rest_framework.utils.field_mapping import get_nested_relation_kwargs

class InheritsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def build_field(self, field_name, info, model_class, nested_depth):
        '''
        inherits the error_messages of the model
        '''
        result: tuple = super().build_field(field_name, info, model_class, nested_depth)

        field = model_class._meta.get_field(field_name)
        error_messages = field.error_messages

        if error_messages:
            result[1]['error_messages'] = field.error_messages

        return result
```