# How to change validation error responses in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to change the JSON, which rest_framework or Django returns when a validation error occurs.

I will use one of my views as example, but I want to change error messages for all of my views. So let say I have this view meant to login users, providing email and password. If these are correct it returns access_token.

If I post only password, it returns error 400:

```
{"email": ["This field is required."]}
```

and if password and email don't match:

```
{"detail": ["Unable to log in with provided credentials."]}
```

what I want would be more like:

```
{"errors": [{"field": "email", "message": "This field is required."}]}

{"errors": [{"non-field-error": "Unable to log in with provided credentials."}]}
```

Now this is my **view**:

```
class OurLoginObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = serializers.AuthTokenSerializer
    model = Token

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            #some magic
            return Response(token)           
        return Response(serializers.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I can access the **serializer.errors** and alter them, but it looks like **only field errors can be accessed that way**, how to change also validation errors created in my serializer's validate method?

This is my **serializer** (it is the same serializer as `rest_framework.authtoken.serializers.AuthTokenSerializer`) but edited, so authentication doesn't require username but email:

```
class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')
        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user:
                if not user.is_active:
                    msg = _('User account is disabled.')
                    raise ValidationError(msg)
                attrs['user'] = user
                return attrs
            else:
                msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
                raise ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "username" and "password"')
            raise ValidationError(msg)
```

Or maybe there is a completely different approach? I will be really thankful for any ideas.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way to change the error style through all the view in your application is to always use `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`, and then implement a [custom exception handler](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) that defines how the error response is created.

Comment: For a different approach see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943985/custom-error-messages-in-django-rest-framework-serializer

Comment: @TomChristie `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` works, but how to set message about exception

Comment: @MatúšBartko Can you post your custom exception that you made to accomplish this, please?

Answer (score 15):

The default structure of DRF when handling errors is something like this:

```
{"email": ["This field is required."]}
```

And you can change this structure to your need by writing a [custom exception handler](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).

Now let's say you want to achieve the following structure:

```
{"errors": [{"field": "email", "message": "This field is required."}]}
```

Your custom exception handler could be something like this:

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Update the structure of the response data.
    if response is not None:
        customized_response = {}
        customized_response['errors'] = []

        for key, value in response.data.items():
            error = {'field': key, 'message': value}
            customized_response['errors'].append(error)

        response.data = customized_response

    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False)
    return Response(serializer.errors.values(), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```