# Django Rest Framework - Non Field Error Custom Message

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943985/custom-error-messages-in-django-rest-framework-serializer) but that doesn't really tell me about non-field errors.

My Model is:

```
class DeviceContact(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    contact_sid = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_index=True)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=250, db_index=True)
    contact_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='mobile')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("contact_sid", "contact_email", "contact_name")


class DeviceContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceContact
        fields = ('contact_sid', 'contact_name', 'contact_email', 'contact_type')
```

How do I return a custom error message when the `unique_together` condition fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `unique_together` set on a model, the serializer will automatically [generate a `UniqueTogetherValidator` that is used](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator) to check their uniqueness. You can confirm this by looking at the output of the serializer, and introspecting what Django REST framework automatically generates:

```
print(repr(DeviceContractSerializer()))
```

You can then alter the `validators` that are set to include your custom `UniqueTogetherValidator` with a custom `message` argument set up.

```
UniqueTogetherValidator(
    queryset=DeviceContract.objects.all(),
    fields=('contact_sid', 'contact_email', 'contact_name', ),
    message='This was not a unique combination within the system, pick a different one.'
)
```

Comment: how to change `non_field_errors` key to specific one?

Answer (score 1):

How about overriding the `DeviceContact`'s `save` method, intercepting the exception, and then re-throwing it to your liking?

```
class MySuperDuperException(Exception):
    pass

class DeviceContact(models.Model):
    [...]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super(DeviceContact,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        catch DeviceContact.IntegrityError as e:
            throw MySuperDuperException()
```

Comment: interesting way of doing it. is there a way of doing this without touching the actual model?

Comment: I believe the serializer has a save API as well. You may be able to do your wrappering there.