# How can I access and change the default model error messages for django.contrib.auth User model?

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I am wondering how I can make custom error messages for the default user model in django 1.8. I am not trying to use model forms. I can find information on how to change the error messages on model forms, or on my own models, but on the actual User model, I don't understand. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I am not looking for error messages in django rest framework. I am trying to edit django's default User model error messages.

Comment: In what context would you be using the error messages outside of a ModelForm though?

Comment: I am using django rest framwork and angular for the front end. so in order to not have to do complicated things to make them all work together, i am just hard coding the form.

Comment: You will probably need to implement your own User model, as most error messages are set on the fields (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py). What is it you are exactly trying to do?

Comment: I am just trying to change the error messages at the database level of the User model. So for example: I submit an invalid email address, and it currently returns: "email: ["Enter a valid email address."]" but for me it would be much easier if it would return something different. Ill look at this git link now thanks.

Comment: If you're using DRF, you can set the validation messages on the Serializer.

Comment: oh cool...do you know where or how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom error messages in Django Rest Framework serializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943985/custom-error-messages-in-django-rest-framework-serializer)

Comment: This seems to be mainly about django-rest-framework’s handling of validation.

Comment: its not about django rest. I was very specific to ask about how to change user error messages on django models.