# Overwrite django restframework CreateModelMixin serializer error message

Tags: python, django, serialization, error-handling, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Restframework 3.3.3, and I am trying to use the generic views, but I was hoping to overwrite the serializer validation error message. I got the following code, which got a "name field cannot be blank" when the name field is not given.

```
class PositionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """Get the Position list, or add another Position only when you are admin"""
    renderer_classes = ((BrowsableAPIRenderer, JSONRenderer))        
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Position.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = PositionSerializer
```

My question is: is there a way to customize the error messages. 
The following methods dose not work for me:
(1). Overwrite the init method in the serializer class:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].error_messages['required'] = 'My custom required msg'
```

(2). Give the error message in the serializer class:

```
class PositionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Position
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
        extra_kwargs = {"name": {"required": _("Customized message goes here")}}
```

Any advises are welcomed, thanks in advance

Comment: Why it is `MyModel` instead of `Position` in your serializer?

Comment: No this problem, edited already. Still cannot figure out why the error message cannot be customized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom error messages in Django Rest Framework serializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943985/custom-error-messages-in-django-rest-framework-serializer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it right with serializer, you just forgot to put it inside `error_messages`

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class PositionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
        extra_kwargs = {"name": {"error_messages": {"blank": _("Customized message goes here")}}}
```

Also you can try setting this message in model. Using `blank`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(..., error_messages={'blank': _("Customized message goes here")})
```

Comment: I got an `name '_' is not defined` error when I use the code. When I get ride of the _, the customized error message still don't show up.

Comment: @shady does it give any error, what response do you get?

Comment: It look like it cannot recognize the underscore before the  error message. When I remove the underscore, it looks all good, but still got an ` "name": ["This field may not be blank." ]` error message. @Sardorbek Imomaliev

Comment: @shady try my second suggestion and change this field in model

Comment: @ Sardorbek Imomaliev It is not working, I had try both.

Comment: @shady it should be `blank` instead of `required` fixed my answer

Comment: @ Sardorbek Imomaliev It does not work, though I add unqiue in model error_messages, the message popup when the name is not unique.

Comment: @shady There is something wrong with your code not with method. Paste your exact code in your post

Comment: Solved it ..., sorry, I make a typo.Your method is right.

Comment: I was wondering if there is way to provide a wrap for the error message. Like `{"name":["Erorr"]}`  to something like: `{"Status":False, "ErrMsg":{"name":["Error"]}}`.

Comment: @shady there is http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling. But this is whole another question)) If you will have any problems, just create new one and ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can go as in your example 1, but instead of "required" use keyword "blank":

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PositionSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].error_messages['blank'] = 'My custom required msg'
```

Comment: No luck, It is not working. I am using the `generic.ListCreateAPIView`.

Comment: In serializer __init__ method make sure that, when you call super, you call with your class...  For example, if your serializer is PositionSerializer, call it as:  super(PositionSerializer, self),.....   I'll  edit example in my answer to match serializer name