# Configure DRF to return errors with an id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework does it's own validations. For example when creating a user it can return something like this:

```
{
    "username": [
        "A user with that username already exists."
    ],
    "password": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
    "name": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ]
}
```

Is there an easy way to return an `id error` instead of a text message? And if it is possible where do I find the id errors meanings? For example, if id error 1 is `A user with that username already exists.` and id error 2 is `This field may not be blank.`:

```
{
    "username": [
        "1"
    ],
    "password": [
        "2"
    ],
    "name": [
        "2"
    ]
}
```

So then in the applications that uses this server can use their own texts (for example, handle different laguages).

I don't want to use my own validations or change the error message. I want to send the id of the error. It's something that DRF should have, but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom error messages in Django Rest Framework serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943985/custom-error-messages-in-django-rest-framework-serializer)

Comment: I don't want ot use my own validators. I am wondering if there is the possibility tu use drf validators but instead of returning a text message, return an id that I can use in client.

Comment: read the part of `extra_kwargs` in the answer

Comment: You don't understand my question. I suppose drf doesn't have what was looking for. I will have to do it field by field and defining my own ids.

Comment: Actually you can try to define your own exception handling - you can read more about it here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling

If you can somehow and in generic way identify the errors - you can modify the response to your needs.