# How to customize error messages in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

How to customize error messages in django rest framework?

I'm trying to do it clean. Without much code.

But this is what I'm trying to do, it does not work.

Thank you in advance for your attention.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class serializerVenda(serializers.Serializer):

    tipo            = serializers.CharField()
    amount          = serializers.CharField(
        error_messages={
            "required": "Amount cannot be empty."
        })
```

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943985/custom-error-messages-in-django-rest-framework-serializer

Comment: Resolved. Thanks