# How to send error responses back to client in django rest framework?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am newbie to Django rest framework and trying to send custom error messages back to client, where I am using VueJS.

I followed the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943985/custom-error-messages-in-django-rest-framework-serializer) but I am unable to receive error message on client side.

### client-side

```
auth.phoneVerification(this.fullName, this.mobileNo, this.email)
                .then((response)=>{
                  console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                  console.log("Error is ", error)
                })
```

### server-side

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = InterestedUser
        fields = ('full_name', 'phone_no', 'email')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['full_name'].error_messages['required'] = 'Please provide your full name.'
        self.fields['phone_no'].error_messages['required'] = 'Please provide your mobile number.'
        self.fields['email'].error_messages['required'] = 'Please provide your email id.'
```

views.py

```
class UserView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        print("requested data is ", request.data)

        if not serializer.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(serializer.errors)

        print("serialiser errors are ",serializer.errors)
```

In console I am unable to receive the message as provided by `serializer.errors`

Answer (score 0):

You can return any Django response with proper data, ex:

```
    ....
    return JsonResponse({'errors': serializer.errors}, status=500)
```

Comment: I am still getting ```Error is  Error: Request failed with status code 400``` and not the error message

Comment: @VINEETSHARMA Check your authentication method