# Is it best practice to validate fields in ModelSerializer for the fields that already have validators in Django model by accessing the the database?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

for example I have a django model as

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(required=True, unique=True)
```

Isnt it **redundant** and against **DRY principle** to validate again in the ModelSerializer as following?

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
    def validate_email(self, email):
        try:
            User.objects.get(email=email)
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Email address already used")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
```

The **validate_email** method feels kind of against the DRY PRINCIPLE and **wrong in this context** since we have to access Database to validate in this method.
please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't have to validate the data again in the serializer** if you have validation already in model level. In your case, the difference is the ***error message*** that you'll get from the API.
By default, DRF return **`{'field_name':['This field must be unique']}`** response in case of unique validation fail

Quoting [@dirkgroten's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252711/dirkgroten)

> Note that to override the generic error message, you don't need to re-validate either. Just use the extra_kwargs attribute on the serializer as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943985/custom-error-messages-in-django-rest-framework-serializer/26975268#26975268)

Comment: Note that to override the generic error message, you don't need to re-validate either. Just use the `extra_kwargs` attribute on the serializer as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26975268/1252711)

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for the info :)