# How can I get API error response in desired format?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This is how I am getting the error messages. By default, I am getting `serializer.errors` as dictionary of list.
[image]

And I want them in list of dictionary format.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ7jO.png]

How can I get API error response in desired format?

Comment: Do you use pydantic?

Comment: A field can have multiple errors hence the list

Comment: @Suman no i don't

Answer (score 0):

You can change the error format of Rest framework. For more information and a way for doing it (for example change the list type to dictionary (object type)) please check the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855409/customize-error-message-in-django-rest/63371092#63371092) question.